# Where can I get Google Sketchup 7.1?

Tags: sketchup

I'd like to download Google Sketchup 7.1.   Google's page shows version `8.0` but I need version `7.1`.  Where can I find it?

Comment: What language and framework is being used for programming this?

Comment: @leppie: SketchUp has a Ruby interface!

Answer (score 4):

http://sketchup.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60107

Comment: The link provided in the answer above only downloads the PRO version. I am looking for the regular, non-PRO version of 7.1.